# How do I test if a Windows share exists and is ready to be mounted?

Tags: windows, mount

How do I test if a Windows share exists before I attempt to mount the share?

Regards
Hendre

Comment: I also wonder the best way to do this, I use a script to do some basic tests, to check im on the correct network, and ping test to the server. I always wondered how to test that the server is actually the server with the share or just another machine on the same IP.

Comment: You pose an interesting question, running a service on the machine that can handle both the ping health check and machine identification might be a solution. What also comes to mind is the definition of a machine. What parts needs to be the same before you decided that the machine is in fact the machine you are targeting. If the hard drive has been removed, is it a new machine?

Comment: To structure my original question better: What are the possible points of failure when attempting to mount a Windows share?

Comment: 1. The target host is down. 2. The share on the host does not exist. 3. There is a network connectivity issue. 4. The share credentials have changed. The firewall on the host is blocking the mount request. 5. The cifs-utils package is not installed.